# What sources does go use for package 'roots', other than $GOROOT and $GOPATH?

Tags: go

When I try to `vet` my Go code and don't have the packages to import in-scope, I usually get a message like this:

```
foo.go:12:2: cannot find package "api/test/metadata/v1" in any of:
    /golang-root/src/api/test/metadata/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /path/to/home/dir/foo/bar/baz/src/api/test/metadata/v1 (from $GOPATH)
    /path/to/home/dir/foo/bar/src/config/src/api/test/metadata/v1
    /path/to/home/dir/foo/bar/src/platform/quux/src/api/test/metadata/v1
```

I could be wrong, but it looks like this is saying that the latter two lines are drawn from something other than `$GOPATH`/`$GOROOT`. It's not stated where they *are* drawn from, though. Where do those come from?

(The place I want it to look is /path/to/home/dir/foo/bar/src/config/**go**/api/test/metadata/v1, because it is a compiled protocol buffer. But answering that is secondary to trying to understand what's going on.)

Comment: Are you using modules (do you have `$GO11MODULE` set and do you have `go.mod` file)? Is you project in `$GOPATH`?

Comment: No to the first. The project I am trying to vet is not directly in GOPATH. Neither of those seem relevant to my question, though; where are these additional paths coming from?

Comment: You should show the foo.go file, especially the imports and where foo.go file is located

Comment: Those are irrelevant. The only thing that's relevant is that it's importing `api/test/metadata/v1`, which is obvious from the question as originally written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely a problem of a badly-worded error message from Go. All entries from the line with `(from $GOPATH)` onward are from the `$GOPATH`. There are no other sources. (I have made this an issue on the golang project and submitted a PR to make it more helpful.)